# Ubuntu server and services

Tags: server, ssh, mysql, dns, nginx

I've been using Linux+Plesk Virtual Server as a web server for a while, but I want to give a try on doing it manually, so my question is:

I'll have a server which is: 80GB HDD, 4GB RAM, 1TB Bandwith, 1 Dedicated IP.
And I use the following things on my Virtual nowadays:

- Mail server
- DNS server
- Apache + PHP 5.5 + MySQL
- FTP
- SSH

My question is, **without Plesk**, can I achieve manually all those functionalities -**know that I am not a terminal pro**-, actually upgrading some of them to look like that with ubuntu server?:

- Mail server (with a nice webmail included)
- DNS server
- nginx + PHP 5.5 + MySQL + MongoDB
- FTP + SFTP
- SSH
- GIT Server

**Which ubuntu server should I chose?**

[EDIT]

I almost forgot, I'd like to know how much Bandwith and CPU is using each of my webapps (one per domain usually), and the overall (not just from the webapps, but also mail, dns, etc...) ... usually Plesk does that for me, and I don't know how to measure that without it!

Answer (score 1):

https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/index.html for the LTS or https://help.ubuntu.com/13.10/serverguide/index.html for the most resent release will get you started and showcase some options for you. Finding the LAMP(Linux, apache, MySQL, php) Guide is big step towards beginning your setup. the tutorials there are pretty simple, but well let you get the basics. after that research as always will get you to the finish line.

As for the version of server, well thats a very personal choice. I chose 12.04 because is the the Long term support version, I get my personal server up and running, and it'll stay awesome because it's older and more mature. if your into bleading edge, 13.10 might be worth looking into.

Answer (score 1):

### [Zentyal](http://www.zentyal.org/)

I found Zentyal the other day while looking a GUI to manage my server that is used for web development. It runs and is based on Ubuntu server 12.04 (and might not work on newer versions), so you can install it after installing the Ubuntu server to provide it a web interface, or install it as the server from the start. (the preferred way according to the documentation)

Having a web interface for the supported interactions means that you won't have to become a terminal pro - but learning a few commands to use via ssh couldn't hurt.

Under features you will see that it includes the following functions (that I think you can just enable/disable as needed)

- Mail server with a webmail
- DNS server
- Web server - that should include Apache, PHP and mySQL, but Ubuntu 12.04 does not support PHP 5.5 if I am correct. And you should be able to install MongoDB and nginx, but I am not sure about that.
- FTP with/without authentication.
- Monitor for CPU, RAM, etc., but might not be able to tell how much CPU/Bandwidth each webapp is using (I thinks there is an Apache module for that).

The features don't list ssh and git, but you should be able to install them using the package manager (or apt-get via ssh), they just won't have a GUI for configuration.

I can't say how it performs and feels since I ended up using something else for my server (that does not use Ubuntu 12.04, else I would have used it)